# Sort data by hours | mongodb

Tags: mongodb, meteor, momentjs

Im getting started with Meteor...So I have documents with the following format:

```
{
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "john",
      "time": "12:10:00"    
},
{
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "mark",
      "time": "10:10:00"    
},
{
      "_id": 1,
      "name": "bob",
      "time": "22:10:00"    
}
```

how i can sort this by the low hours to hight hours somthing like : `10:10:00, 12:10:00, 22:10:00`

my code:

```
Template.body.helpers({
    tasks: function(){
      return data.find();
    }
  });
```

html:

```
      <ul>
        {{#each tasks}}
          {{> task}}
        {{/each}}
      </ul>
      <template name="task">
        <li><span class="text">{{name}}</span>, <span class="time">{{time}}</span></li>
      </template>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should be able to give a second parameter to the find function, for a sort. The {} means to find all docs.

```
return data.find({}, { sort: { time: 1 } });
```